# Count how many unique values are there in a column, While satisfying another columns requirement

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

Hello I have data in  a table in the form:

```
Order#           Origin        Status          Date
90028             BG00           30          1/2/2018
90021             BG01           50          2/2/2018
90021             BG01           40          3/2/2018
90028             BG01           20          2/2/2018
```

And I want to count how many unique **order number** are there (count with no duplicate) While being;

**Origin** from BG00
Has a **Status** 30 OR 40
Has a **Date** of today

Help is appreciated as soon as possible.

Comment: Take a look at [this explanation](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria) to see if it helps.

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Write this array formula in **F76**, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

```
{=SUM(IF(("BG00"=$B$76:$B$79)*($C$76:$C$79>=30)*($C$76:$C$79<=40)*(E74=$D$76:$D$79), 1/COUNTIFS($B$76:$B79, "BG00", $A$76:$A$79, $A$76:$A$79, $C$76:$C$79, ">="&30, $C$76:$C$79, "<="&40,$D$76:$D$79,E74)),0)}
```

**Edited:**

**How it works:**

*The First part of the Formula returns `90028` from `A76:A79` since Order ID in Row 1 only matches all three conditons*.

```
{=SUM(IF(("BG00"=$B$76:$B$79)*($C$76:$C$79>=30)*($C$76:$C$79<=40)*(E74=$D$76:$D$79),A76:A79,0))}
```

**N.B.** With the above formula I've purposely Added `A76:A79` to get the value from Range, otherwise The second part is inputting it with `Countifs`as **True** conditions of the IF and it returns 1 (One Match only).

```
{=COUNTIFS($B$76:$B79, "BG00", $A$76:$A$79, $A$76:$A$79, $C$76:$C$79, ">="&30, $C$76:$C$79, "<="&40,$D$76:$D$79,E74)),0)}
```

If Order Id `90028` in `row 4` would match all three conditions `Orgin, Status & Date` then `Countifs` would have return `2`.

*`SUM` & `1/Countifs`, has been added to the formula as "abandoned precaution" otherwise this formula will work without them also.*

```
{=IF(("BG00"=$B$76:$B$79)*($C$76:$C$79>=30)*($C$76:$C$79<=40)*(E74=$D$76:$D$79), COUNTIFS($B$76:$B79, "BG00", $A$76:$A$79, $A$76:$A$79, $C$76:$C$79, ">="&30, $C$76:$C$79, "<="&40,$D$76:$D$79,E74),0)}
```

*`SUM` is quite useful when values from range `A76:A79` need to be added to the criteria.*

**Note,**

- Adjust cell references in formula as needed.
- If you put **Today's** date in **E74** then you must fill *Date column*
  with few similar date values to match with.

Comment: The formula is complex and not straightforward, and the OP will need to adapt it to their own spreadsheet.  Can you add some explanation of how/why it works?

Comment: @fixer1234, it was the only possibility since formula has to test 3 condition Origin, Status & Date to count for unique value.

Comment: @fixer1234  what do you mean by "the OP will need to adapt it to their own spreadsheet?

Comment: @Fam, the site is a knowledge base of solutions to help anyone with similar problems.  You, or any other reader, won't have a spreadsheet that exactly matches this example.  For a solution to be useful, any reader will need to understand how it works in order to adapt it to the specifics of their needs.  This solution is not trivial or obvious to understand, so I suggested that Rajesh add some explanation of how it works in order to make the answer more useful.

Comment: @fixer1234, soon I'll edit & explain that how it works, Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234, I've edited the answer and try to explain at my best that how both parts of the formula works and coordinates each other. Also shown the modified version of the formula which is without `SUM` & `1/COUNTIS`, will help OP and readers too, to adapt it with their worksheets. :-)

Comment: Serving suggestions for clarification: 1) >=30&<=40 means any value in between meets the criteria (ex, 35).  Question defines requirement as 30 or 40.  2) It isn't obvious what 1/countifs does. how it works, why it's there, or how it returns a correct count if count >1.  3) Within the countifs, it isn't obvious how `$A$76:$A$79, $A$76:$A$79` matches multiple potential orders against each value without double counting multiples.  Also, same issue with 30 or 40.  4) Looks like the closing parentheses aren't in the right place.

Comment: @fixer1234, `>=30 & <=40` covers all numbers between `30 & 40` including both `30 & 40`. COUNTIFs is finished the results are used as a divisor with 1 as the numerator. Values that appear in data once appear in the array as 1, but values that appear multiple times will appear as fractional values that correspond to the multiple. (i.e. a value that appears 5 times in data range will generate 5 items in the array with a value of 1/5 = .2). Yes the `Countifs` could works without `A76:A79` also, it's been added for safety considering larger data range as safer side for multiple occurrence.

Comment: Like this one for single data range `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A76:A79,A76:A79))` using same method. Other straight forward formula which also works for OP should `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($B$76:$B79, "BG00",  $C$76:$C$79, ">="&30, $C$76:$C$79, "<="&40,$D$76:$D$79,E74))` returns 1. *But the shown array formula is better and safer too considering larger data range.*

Comment: The numbers between 30 and 40 is different from the requirement of 30 or 40.  Also it looks like the closing parentheses are in the wrong place.  The explanation in the comments doesn't really explain "why" the formula should give the requested result, or even work in general cases outside of this specific example.  In your example, add a duplicate of the row 76 data, and see if you still get the same answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80599/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-fixer1234).